# BottomNavigationView not shown after making it visible again

Tags: android

I am working on an Android App. There is an Activity called HomeActivity which has a BottomNavigationView on it.

There are also several fragments.

From a fragment called SpotsSearch2Fragment I am opening another fragment called NuevoSpot1Fragment:

```
 ivNuevoSpot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NuevoSpot1Fragment nextFrag= new NuevoSpot1Fragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.frame_layout, nextFrag, "mapaSpots")
                        .addToBackStack(null)

                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

At NuevoSpot1Fragment I am hiding the BottomNavigationView from the parent Activity:

```
((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setNavigationVisibility(false);
```

which is working right, the BottomNavigationView disappears.

This is the function in HomeActivity that is called by the fragments to hide or show the BottomNavigationView:

```
public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (bottomNavigationView.isShown() && !visible) {
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if (!bottomNavigationView.isShown() && visible){
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

There is a button at NuevoSpot1Fragment that should open the fragment SpotsSearch2Fragment again.

```
btnCerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
```

Therefore I have included at  SpotsSearch2Fragment the code:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("JSON", "on resume spot");

        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setNavigationVisibility(true);
    }
```

My issues is that going back to SpotsSearch2Fragment from  NuevoSpot1Fragment the BottomNavigationView in SpotsSearch2Fragment is still invisible.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Showing not visible BottomNavigationView when it should became visible:

[image]

Comment: did u try getVisiblity() instead of isShown()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if (bottomNavigationView.isShown() && !visible) {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if (!bottomNavigationView.isShown() && visible){
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

With:

```
public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if ((bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) && !visible) {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if ((bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) && visible){
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

EDIT: And i recommend to you include in fragments this code to avoid `NullPointerException` in Fragments, and call `setNavigationVisibility` method from `mActivity` variable and declare `mActivity` globally in Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof HomeActivity){
        mActivity = (HomeActivity) context;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have changed the code like your proposal, but still not visible

Comment: you can tell me where you init a BottomNavigationView in which block of your activity or fragment

Comment: maybe bottomnavigationview is destruct and not creates again

Comment: It is created at HomeActivity onCreate method:

Comment: bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                    findViewById(R.id.navigation);

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if (bottomNavigationView.isShown() && !visible) {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if (!bottomNavigationView.isShown() && visible){
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

With:

```
public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if (bottomNavigationView.getVisibilty() && !visible) {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if (!bottomNavigationView.getVisibilty() && visible){
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am geting a warning "Operator && cannot be applied to int"

Comment: I have change the proposed code with:   public void setNavigationVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !visible) {
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if (bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.GONE && visible){
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
This way I don´t get the warning, but remains  not visible.

Comment: Yes I forgot " == View.VISIBLE". 
I tried to run something similar to your code and found that if you replace:

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.frame_layout, nextFrag, "mapaSpots")
                        .addToBackStack(null)

                        .commit();

with: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, nextFrag, "mapaSpots")
                        .addToBackStack(null)

                        .commit();
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

all u need to change is getVisibilty() and also setVisibilty()